# I want to show progress bar inside of a bootstrap modal and my modal is correctly displaying but the progress bar inside of it isn't showing

Tags: javascript, html

This is what I have tried- I added the bootstrap modal and inside of that modal's content part I am trying to add dynamic progress bar but the javascript that I have wrote for the progress bar doesn't seem to work. Can anyone tell me if my logic is wrong or there's some other issue?

```js
$('#myModal').modal({
    backdrop: 'static',
    keyboard: false,
    show: false
  });

 
  
  $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
   
    var current_progress = 0;
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        current_progress += 10;
        $("#dynamic")
        .css("width", current_progress + "%")
        .attr("aria-valuenow", current_progress)
        .text(current_progress + "% Complete");
        if (current_progress >= 100)
        {
            clearInterval(interval);
            
        }
           
    }, 1000);
    
  });
  
  $('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
      // reset modal
     if ($('#myModal').data('reenable')) {
         $(this).removeData();
         $('#myModal').modal({
            show: true
         });
     }
  });
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <h1></h1>
      <p>Click button to run demo..</p>
      <a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal">Submit</a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title in" id="myModalLabel">Please Wait</h4>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body center-block">
           
            <div class="progress">
              <div id="dynamic" class="progress-bar progress-bar-success progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%">
                <span id="current-progress"></span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default hide" data-dismiss="modal" id="btnClose">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
      </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

[This is how the output looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNfEP.png)

Comment: Hi, your code snippet throws error. You can edit it or you can link to a JSFiddle or CodePen.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're working with your JS references for bootstrap/jQuery after your modal's scripts. Changed your code a bit to make it work after jQuery loaded and it worked for me in a `test.html`

Try your code like that in a separated file:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        initializeModal();
    
    
    });
    
function initializeModal() {
        $('#myModal').modal({
    backdrop: 'static',
    keyboard: false,
    show: false
  });

 
  
  $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
   
    var current_progress = 0;
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        current_progress += 10;
        $("#dynamic")
        .css("width", current_progress + "%")
        .attr("aria-valuenow", current_progress)
        .text(current_progress + "% Complete");
        if (current_progress >= 100)
        {
            clearInterval(interval);
            
        }
           
    }, 1000);
    
  });
  
  $('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
      // reset modal
     if ($('#myModal').data('reenable')) {
         $(this).removeData();
         $('#myModal').modal({
            show: true
         });
     }
  });
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
      <h1></h1>
      <p>Click button to run demo..</p>
      <a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal">Submit</a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title in" id="myModalLabel">Please Wait</h4>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body center-block">
           
            <div class="progress">
              <div id="dynamic" class="progress-bar progress-bar-success progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%">
                <span id="current-progress"></span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default hide" data-dismiss="modal" id="btnClose">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
      </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div><!-- /.modal -->
    

    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: No problem. Always try to load your javascript code after all your JS libraries, so then you know everything will be working when using jQuery/Bootstrap. Mark as solved?